# Is it possible to stop play-store from updating all the apps automatically? (some automated way, not via settings)

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I know there is a setting in Play-store, 'do not auto-update apps'. I am not looking for that one.

I am looking for an automated way, like using ADB or some other code by which I can stop apps from auto-updating.

EDIT: 
I have root access, though it is better if it can be done without root.

Comment: There is separate flag for each app too. Auto update is a flag in Play Store and not particular app, so you can't use adb to toogle  that.

Comment: @global_warming I changed that flag in database to 0 (don't auto update) but still when I logged in from my google account, they got updated, while 'auto_update' column for each app remained at 0.